# How can I speed up a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, query-performance

Here is an interview question I just had. I would like to know what a good answer to this would have been and what the different options would be.

> We have a stored procedure that is taking 26 seconds to return
>   information that is grabbed from 5 tables. Our server times out after
>   25 seconds. How can you solve this problem?

This is not verbatim but it is close to the question that was asked. I had no clue, and I don't even think we went into that kind of detail in our db class. All I could think of telling them is to make sure that the tables are indexed and I don't even know if that is right.

Here's an example of how this could look on creation:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOrderForCustomers(@CustID varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM orders o
    JOIN state s ON s.stateID = o.stateID
    JOIN customers c ON c.customerID = o.customerID
    JOIN items i ON i.itemID = o.itemID
    JOIN parts p ON p.partListID = o.partListID
WHERE c.customerID = @CustID
END
```

Once again this would be taking slightly more time than the timeout time allows.

- What are my options for speeding up this stored procedure syntactically?
- What are the different types of metadata that might help solve the problem?
- What practices should be avoided that are seen in the procedure above?
- (As a non-required aside question) Would it be acceptable to tell an interviewer that I would ask the real-life question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: [Related meta question](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/2525).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazingly broad question but a couple of simple answers.

- Indexing like you suggested.  Make sure the appropriate indexes exist and if the need is great enough make sure they are all covering.
- Get rid of the *.  Specify the columns you need.  If you are pulling across 100 columns over a million rows that's going to be a LOT of data.  If you only need 3 columns only specify 3 columns.
- Change the timeout.  This sounds hokey but honestly sometimes it really is the answer.  SQL Server (for example) doesn't actually have a timeout so the problem is on the connection side.  Have them increase the timeout to 30 seconds (assuming this is an acceptable amount of time, and it frequently won't be).
- Make sure it's the DBMS's fault.  It's very possible you are having a problem on the connection side that's causing it to take 5-10 seconds just to connect.  Fix that and you are well within your time.